# How do I avoid the extra copy in the generic function template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

**Background**

I have some generic code for persistence that uses `boost::variant` to store multiple types.  While outputting values, I had to write a converter function `protected_backslash_n`, which does nothing, in the default case, but return the same value back.

In the specialised case where the template parameter is a `std::string` I use `boost::regex_replace()` to search for `\n` and replace it with `\\n`.

**Question**

*The code works fine, but it would be nice if I could get rid of the extra copy in the generic case, due to the return-by-value*.

Is there a way to do this while allowing the specialised `std::string` version to work fine?

I tried changing the return value to `T const&`, but then the specialised version won't match up.

**Error**

```
GetPipedValues.hpp:15:21: error: template-id ‘protect_backslash_n<std::string>’ for ‘std::string pitbull::protect_backslash_n(const string&)’ does not match any template declaration
```

**Code**

```
template<typename T>
inline T protect_backslash_n( T const& orig )
{
    return orig;  // BAD: extra copy - how do I get rid of this?
}

template<>
inline std::string protect_backslash_n<std::string>( std::string const& orig )
{
    boost::regex expr("(\\n)");
    std::string  fmt("(\\\\n)");
    return boost::regex_replace(
        orig, expr, fmt, boost::match_default | boost::format_all
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly and checked whether the copy actually causes any additional code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make it a template, but just an overload. The compiler will choose that function over a template instantiation, if the parameter matches.

```
std::string protect_backslash_n( std::string const& orig);
```

Comment: +1 works great!  I will have to comment the code to explain what is going on - thx.

Answer (score 0):

That should be simple:

```
  template <typename T>
  T const& protect_backslash_n(T const& orig)
  { 
    return orig; 
  }
```

And the `std::string` version as you had it. Maybe you will need additional overloads, e.g. taking a nonconst reference. In C++11 that function should mimic `std::forward<T>` in the default case.